# Deleting other people's comments on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-comments

On Facebook it appears other people can delete your comments. When can this happen, in the context of writing on someone's timeline (so not including scenarios where a group admin deletes a comment)? For example is it whoever you replied to can delete your comment? Will you get a notification if someone deletes your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post owner can delete any comment, or if you are replying to anyone, that person can delete your comment. You will not get any notification. Deleting comment will not notify to the commenter.

Similar a group admin or page admin can delete any comment and comment poster will not get any notification.